# Work (see) in the workspace with the exact elements in a print layout in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, layouts, printing, workspace

Is there any possibility to see (to work with) exactly what you get in a print layout in QGIS 3?

I have an A3 layout, at 1:45000 scale, but i cannot arrange all elements because I get a different result from the one I seen in the workspace (labels, arrangements of some elements, etc).

What I have to do to work like WYSIWYG (workspace - print layout)?

Comment: You can preview in the layout itself after rearranging stuff. How does that not work for you?

Comment: Hello, can you explain what does change ? You have talk about label but what are the other things ? Can you share screenshot of print layout and workspace differences ?